# textchanged event of textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I want to fire the textchanged event of textbox after the user enters text/data in the textbox in vb.net. But the event is getting fired as soon as the user enters the first word in the textbox.

is there any way I can solve this problem? I tried googling but didnt get satisfactory solution..

Comment: It's a normal behavior for `TextChanged` event for textbox. Can you explain more what do you really want to do?

Comment: I want the user to enter his empid in the first textbox and using this empid I want to fetch his name from the database and display it in the second textbox for which i wanted to use the textchanged event of the first textbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TextChanged** Event is triggered when there is any change in the TextBox.
If you want to invoke something after user finishes up then try using **LostFocus** Event of the TextBox which will be triggered as user leaves the focus from textbox.